# Alignment property of Pens tool in WinForms graphics

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

When I want to draw a rectangle in c# using pen tools If the rectangle width and height is less then the pens width then program draw nothing in from if pens  **alignment**  property  **Inset**.But when I set **alignment**  *center* then It print a rectangle. which is not size of my rectangle. Actually what happened at that time?

**example:**

```
      Pen p = new Pen(Color.Black, 300);
      p.Alignment = PenAlignment.Center;
      g.DrawRectangle(p, 100, 100,10, 10);
      p.Dispose();
```

The output figure is:

[image]

But how it is possible to draw a rectangle of 1o pixel width,hight with a pen of 300 pixel width?

Comment: This is like painting the Mona Lisa with a broom and asking how to get the smile.

Answer (score 0):

So, basically, when the rectangle width or height smaller then 300px, you want to draw a black filled rectangle?

```
void DrawRectangle(Graphics g, Color pencolor, int penwidth, Rectangle x)
{
    if(x.Width < penwidth || x.Height < penHeight)
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(pencolor);
        p.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
        g.FillRectangle(p, x);
        p.Dispose();
    }
    else
    {
        Pen p = new Pen(pencolor, penwidth);
        p.Alignment = PenAlignment.Inset;
        g.DrawRectangle(p, x);
        p.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Hope that helps.